# Problems about python if condition

Tags: python, if-statement

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/etfOX.png]

question1:The if condition is not working. Every time it quits
question2:(for i in range(1, ret[0]+1):
NameError: name 'ret' is not defined)

Comment: Please show us your code, where abouts the conditional is, and what error you receive

Comment: remove initialize action `action = ""`

Comment: if i remove the action,the error will be  "action is not defined"

Comment: If you set action to `""` directly before checking it's value, why do you expect it to be anything else?

Comment: yeah,I have already fixed that problem.Thank you so much.Now I got a new problem T-T.

Comment: Do you know what `NameError: name "var" is not defined` means?  If you haven't created a variable (i.e. name) before you use it, it is an error.  You never create `ret`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of what you have:

```
action = ""
if action == "stat": # Not true, action == ""
    # stuff
elif action == "list": # Not true, action == ""
    # stuff
elif action == "retr": # Not true, action == ""
    # stuff
else: # Looks like this is where we will end up
    exit()
```

It's no surprise you are quitting every time, since you have hard coded a condition to make it quit every time.

You say if you remove the `action = ""` you get a `NameError` saying `action` is not defined... that is because you never set it to anything... I'm not sure what you expected the if block to do as written.  You need something like this:

```
action = a_function_that_gets_info_from_user_and_returns_a_string()
```

This will set `action` to something that might pass your `if` block.

---

As a side note, you should't do screenshots for your questions.  Instead, copy/paste; it's the polite thing to do.  Now I have to hand type your code to illustrate what's wrong instead of copying it myself.

Comment: i am sorry .I tried copy/paste but it said I should add context to explain the code section....i added context for my code but it failed.So I had to upload the picture...I feel so sorry about it

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation seems to be way off. It should be the same amount throughout the code. [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests four spaces for indentation.

You are probably receiving an `IndentationError`.

---

You seem to mention that `"Every time it quits"`. This is **expected**. Your code, `pp.quit()` will quit the program if `action` does not equal either `'stat'`, `'list'`, or `'retr'`, which is what is happening.

Comment: I disagree... the indentation looks fine to me, except in the `else` block, but I don't think that would raise an error.

Comment: @SethMMorton The `else` bit is where I am talking about. The code would go there because `action !=` any of those options, hence the error

Comment: My point is that because the `pp.quit()` is consistent within it's own block (the `else`) it is legal python, just bad style.  It doesn't raise an `IndentationError`.  Try it.